# LibGDX Tiled (TMX) Maps + Scene2D, bugs when rendering both

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d, tiled

So I've recently started tinkering with LibGDX (desktop only, at the moment) in Java. I'm mildly experienced with other type of OGL libraries in other languages (namely SFML in C++) and quite experienced with the Java language itself, so I tackled LibGDX pretty confidently; and while the results were mostly positive, there's a bug that I just can't figure out.

What I want to achieve is simple: draw a map (**Tiled .tmx**), draw a **Sprite** (soon-to-be "player") *inbetween layers 1 and 2*, and render a couple of GUI widgets on top of all that, using a scene2D **stage**. I've managed to achieve this partially.

Here's my **Game** class, it's pretty messy from so much switching things around just to try, but it's pretty clear what it attempts to do:

```
public class Game extends ApplicationAdapter 
{
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Texture img;
    private Sprite playerSprite;
    private TiledMap tiledMap;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer;

    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("trchar000.png");
        playerSprite = new Sprite(img, 0, 0, 32, 48);

        playerSprite.setPosition(32, 192);

        InputHandler.init();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputHandler());

        stage = new TestStage(playerSprite);

        // inputs
        InputMultiplexer im = new InputMultiplexer(stage, new InputHandler());
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(im);

        // tiles
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        camera.update();
        tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("map2.tmx");
        tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update();
        tiledMapRenderer.setView(camera);

        int[] groundLayers = {0};
        int[] topLayers = {1};

        // render layer1 -> player -> layer 2
        // the .tmx map doesn't have any other layers (just those 2)
        tiledMapRenderer.render(groundLayers);

        // removing these 3 lines solves the issue, but doesn't render the player
        // I've also tried using my regular SpriteBatch instance; same results
        // Also, I tried creating a class that extends OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer and overriding the render() method, so that it would draw the player inbetween layers, but again, same results.
        tiledMapRenderer.getBatch().begin();
        tiledMapRenderer.getBatch().draw(playerSprite, playerSprite.getX(), playerSprite.getY());
        tiledMapRenderer.getBatch().end();

        tiledMapRenderer.render(topLayers);

        batch.begin();

        // just to try, I'm rendering the stage here (not calling it's draw() method). Removing this for loop solves the issue, but doesn't render the GUI
        for(Actor a : stage.getActors())
            a.draw(batch, 1);

        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
        img.dispose();
        tiledMapRenderer.dispose();
        stage.dispose();
    }
}
```

Also, here's my **TestStage** class:

```
public class TestStage extends Stage {

    private Skin skin;
    private BitmapFont newDefaultFont;

    public TestStage(Sprite player)
    {
        super(new ScreenViewport());

        // skin
        FreeTypeFontGenerator freeTypeFontGenerator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("segoeui.ttf"));
        FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
        parameter.size = 14;
        newDefaultFont = freeTypeFontGenerator.generateFont(parameter);

        skin = new Skin();
        skin.add("default-font", newDefaultFont, BitmapFont.class);
        FileHandle fileHandle = Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json");
        FileHandle atlasFile = fileHandle.sibling("uiskin.atlas");

        if (atlasFile.exists()) {
            skin.addRegions(new TextureAtlas(atlasFile));
        }

        skin.load(fileHandle);

        final TextButton button = new TextButton("This is a Button", skin, "default");
        button.setPosition(250, 250);
        button.setWidth(150);
        button.setHeight(40);

        final Label lbl = new Label("Test", skin);

        this.addActor(lbl);
        this.addActor(button);
    }

}
```

Now here's the deal; this is what it looks like if a try to render everything (as shown in my Game class' **render()** method):

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWHeT.png)

The player, GUI, and layer 2 are rendered correctly, but the layer 1 is all bugged out, and I can't figure out why.

Now, here's how it looks like if a don't render the player, removing the line
`tiledMapRenderer.getBatch().draw(playerSprite, playerSprite.getX(), playerSprite.getY());`

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjMEA.png)

Everything renders fine.
Also, here's what it looks like if I decide not to render the stage actors, commenting this loop:

```
for(Actor a : stage.getActors())
    a.draw(batch, 1);
```

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC7QV.png)

Again, everything renders fine.

The only other classes in my project are the default DesktopLauncher class, and an InputProcessor which I'm sure has nothing to do with this.
This is my first question here ever; I just can't figure this out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stage should be rendered differently... Using `stage.act(); stage.draw();` methods (instead of the loop where you iterate through stage actors).

Comment: That's how I had it originally. Same results.